# How to get authenticated users cached on drupal with or without authcache

Tags: session, drupal, caching, memcached, apc

Could use some help. I have a drupal6 install that im having trouble with in terms of caching for authenticated users. Boost is handling the none authenticated caching very well. With my current setup, sessions cannot be created at all, when attempting to login the result is "You are not authorized to view this page". Memcache and apc are installed on the server and working according to phpinfo. Here is my current setup (without cacherouter):

```
include_once('./sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc');
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['session_inc'] =  './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-session.inc';
$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
'127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default',
'127.0.0.1:11212' => 'block',
'127.0.0.1:11213' => 'content',
'127.0.0.1:11214' => 'filter',
'127.0.0.1:11215' => 'form',
'127.0.0.1:11216' => 'menu',
'127.0.0.1:11217' => 'page',
'127.0.0.1:11218' => 'update',
'127.0.0.1:11219' => 'views',
'127.0.0.1:11221' => 'session',
'127.0.0.1:11222' => 'users'
);

$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
'cache' => 'default',
'cache_block' => 'block',
'cache_content' => 'content',
'cache_filter' => 'filter',
'cache_form' => 'form',
'cache_menu' => 'menu',
'cache_page' => 'page',
'cache_update' => 'update',
'cache_views' => 'views',
'session' => 'session',
'users' => 'users'
);
```

Before this setup, I was using cacherouter with authcache and had apc as the engine. Users could log in, but there was no actual caching happening for authenticated users. I have been reading everything I could find on this to get it going, doing various test and changing configurations, but without success. Here was the previous setup:

```
$conf['cacherouter'] = array(
'default' => array(
'engine' => 'apc',
'server' => array('127.0.0.1:11211'),
'shared' => TRUE,
'prefix' => '',
'path' => 'storage_bin/filecache',
'static' => FALSE
),
);

$conf['cache_inc'] = './sites/all/modules/authcache/authcache.inc';

$conf['memcache_servers'] = array(
'127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default',
'127.0.0.1:11212' => 'block',
'127.0.0.1:11213' => 'content',
'127.0.0.1:11214' => 'filter',
'127.0.0.1:11215' => 'form',
'127.0.0.1:11216' => 'menu',
'127.0.0.1:11217' => 'page',
'127.0.0.1:11218' => 'update',
'127.0.0.1:11219' => 'views'
);

$conf['memcache_bins'] = array(
'cache' => 'default',
'cache_block' => 'block',
'cache_content' => 'content',
'cache_filter' => 'filter',
'cache_form' => 'form',
'cache_menu' => 'menu',
'cache_page' => 'page',
'cache_update' => 'update',
'cache_views' => 'views'
);
```

The site is visible at www.thewildside.com. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into this, my solution was to ditch cacherouter (did not perform as expected), authcache(too beta), and boost (simply to avoid hitting apache at all for cached pages)… proceeding with Memcache API (the drupal module), memcache (the caching system), apc and varnish (3.0). Memcache API allows me to cache both to RAM via memcache and to the drupal db as backup in case memcache is not available (via memcache.db.inc). Benchmark to determine how much RAM to use for each cache component. I can also keep session info in memcache, but I have not noticed a great performance gain with this, so you may choose not to include memcache-session.inc. Create memcache instances for each drupal cache db (or use one default instance). Setup a cache bin for each instance you've created, and throw in reverse proxy settings and default ttl. Here is my whats in my setting.php file;

```
$conf = array(
'cache_inc'        => './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.db.inc',
'memcache_key_prefix' => 'ws',
'session_inc'      => './sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-session.inc',
'memcache_servers' => array(
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside.sock' => 'default',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_apachesolr.sock' => 'apachesolr',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_block.sock' => 'block',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_content.sock' => 'content',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_filter.sock' => 'filter',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_form.sock' => 'form',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_media_youtube_status.sock' => 'media_youtube_status',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_menu.sock' => 'menu',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_objects.sock' => 'objects',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_page.sock' => 'page',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_path.sock' => 'path',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_rules.sock' => 'rules',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_update.sock' => 'update',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_views.sock' => 'views',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_views_data.sock' => 'views_data',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_session.sock' => 'session',
'unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached_wildside_users.sock' => 'users'),
'memcache_bins' => array(
'cache' => 'default',
'cache_apachesolr' => 'apachesolr',
'cache_block' => 'block',
'cache_content' => 'content',
'cache_filter' => 'filter',
'cache_form' => 'form',
'cache_media_youtube_status' => 'media_youtube_status',
'cache_menu' => 'menu',
'cache_objects' => 'objects',
'cache_page' => 'page',
'cache_path' => 'path',
'cache_rules' => 'rules',
'cache_update' => 'update',
'cache_views' => 'views',
'cache_views_data' => 'views_data',
'session' => 'session',
'users' => 'users'),
);

$conf['https'] = TRUE;
$conf['mimedetect_magic'] = '/usr/share/file/magic';
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1');

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])){
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
    }else{
        $_SERVER['HTTPS']='';
    }
}

/* 1 day cache lifetime = 86400 */
$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 86400;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 86400;
```

When setting up Varnish's config file (.vcl), just be sure that the syntax you use corresponds to the version of varnish you have installed.